# Setting default user in Linux/WSL in sideloaded distro

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

With WSL Distros from the Microsoft store they are bundled with a utility to set the default user `ubuntu config --default-user new_user_name`. If i sideload a distro image that option doesn't exist. How can I set default user without it?

Windows 10 Pro Build 19033.1

As for as installing a distro I would download the tar.gz from something like [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/eoan/release-20191115/) and Use `wsl --import <Distro> <InstallLocation> <FileName>` to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method - added in [build 18980](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-18980) - simple, and doesn't require registry modification:

1. Create the `/etc/wsl.conf` file in the WSL distro (if it doesn't already exist).
2. Add the following section to it:

   `[user]`
   `default=<username>`

Comment: I tried, but it did not work for me. Switching user with `su username` works, but the distro keeps logging in as root.

Answer (score 7):

**Warning:** The following registry method is not documented and may change.

- Method 1, Simple but undocumented. Open the Registry Editor. Go to this key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`.
  Double click to expand it. There will be some random strings in curly braces,
  its called [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Go through each one of them until you find the distribution
  name that matches with `DistributionName` registry. Now double click on the
  `DefaultUid` DWORD registry and change the value to the user id that will be
  set to be default. For example, root user id is 0 (zero), normal user id is 1000
  (0x3e8 in hex). Here is an example of WSL distribution entry in registry:

```ini
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\{73d04361-eda8-4c3a-9c74-1eb25937ba99}]
"State"=dword:00000001
"DistributionName"="Debian"
"Version"=dword:00000002
"BasePath"="F:\\Debian"
"Flags"=dword:00000007
"DefaultUid"=dword:000003e8
```

- Method 2, complex but documented. This requires some programming in C language.
  Use the [`WslConfigureDistribution`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wslapi/nf-wslapi-wslconfiguredistribution) function to set the default user id.
  These [WSL APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wslapi/) are written in `wslapi.h` header file in Windows 10 SDK.
  For example, to set normal user (uid = 1000 ) as default in Ubuntu distribution,
  use this:

```c
WslConfigureDistribution(L"Ubuntu", 1000, WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_DEFAULT);
```

This method is used in [WSL distribution launcher](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher/) that is bundled with every
WSL distribution in Windows Store.